# Can i find another alternatives to require.context () of webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, vite

i'm trying to import some pictures in my assets folder dynamically to use it in my carousel component with the webpack function require.context(). But i'm using vite js and there is not webpack with vite js. I tried to find some solutions and i found that vite has an alternative "import.meta.glob()" and i didn't understand how to use it.

Here's the link to the alternative : https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

Here's the code that is not working for me:

```
// imports all images from assets folder
const importAll = (r) =>
r.keys().reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.replace("./", "")] = r(item);
  return acc;
}, {});

const heroTextureImports = importAll(
  require.context("../../assets", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);
```

Here are the assets folder and the images :

[image]

I tried to use the vite alternative like this :

```
// imports all images from assets folder
const importAll = (r) =>
r.keys().reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.replace("./", "")] = r(item);
  return acc;
}, {});

const heroTextureImports = importAll(
  import.meta.glob("../../assets")
  // require.context("../../assets", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);
```

But i didn't add the regex in the context() method `/\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/` and i'm getting this error in the console :

[image]

Do you have a solution ?

Here's the full code of the component :

```
import { Box, Typography, IconButton, useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import NavigateBeforeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NavigateBefore";
import NavigateNextIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NavigateNext";
import { shades } from "../../theme";

// imports all images from assets folder
const importAll = (r) =>
  r.keys().reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.replace("./", "")] = r(item);
  return acc;
}, {});

const heroTextureImports = importAll(
  import.meta.glob("../../assets")
  // require.context("../../assets", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);

const MainCarousel = () => {
  const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");
  return (
     <Carousel
        infiniteLoop={true}
        showThumbs={false}
        showIndicators={false}
        showStatus={false}
        renderArrowPrev={(onClickHandler, hasPrev, label) => (
           <IconButton
              onClick={onClickHandler}
              sx={{
                 position: "absolute",
                 top: "50%",
                 left: "0",
                 color: "white",
                 padding: "5px",
                 zIndex: "10",
              }}
            >
              <NavigateBeforeIcon sx={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
            </IconButton>
          )}
          renderArrowNext={(onClickHandler, hasNext, label) => (
            <IconButton
               onClick={onClickHandler}
               sx={{
                   position: "absolute",
                   top: "50%",
                   right: "0",
                   color: "white",
                   padding: "5px",
                   zIndex: "10",
      }}
    >
      <NavigateNextIcon sx={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
    </IconButton>
  )}
>
  {Object.values(heroTextureImports).map((texture, index) => (
    <Box key={`carousel-image-${index}`}>
      <img
        src={texture}
        alt={`carousel-${index}`}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "700px",
          objectFit: "cover",
          backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
        }}
      />
      <Box
        color="white"
        padding="20px"
        borderRadius="1px"
        textAlign="left"
        backgroundColor="rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"
        position="absolute"
        top="46%"
        left={isNonMobile ? "10%" : "0"}
        right={isNonMobile ? undefined : "0"}
        margin={isNonMobile ? undefined : "0 auto"}
        maxWidth={isNonMobile ? undefined : "240px"}
      >
        <Typography color={shades.secondary[200]}>-- NEW ITEMS</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h1">Summer Sale</Typography>
        <Typography
          fontWeight="bold"
          color={shades.secondary[300]}
          sx={{ textDecoration: "underline" }}
        >
          Discover More
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  ))}
</Carousel>
```

Here the vite config file :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

and my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build",
  "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives -- 
     max-warnings 0",
  "preview": "vite preview"
},
"dependencies": {
   "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
   "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
   "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.1",
   "@mui/material": "^5.14.2",
   "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
   "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.1.1",
   "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.54.2",
   "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
   "formik": "^2.4.2",
   "react": "^18.2.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
   "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
   "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
   "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
   "yup": "^1.2.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

Or is there another way to do this imports dynamically without the need of webpack?

Comment: Your not following the docs you linked. Glob is going to return an object of asynchronous module factories. Try `const textures = Object.fromEntries(await Promise.all(Object.entries(import.meta.glob('whatever')).map(async ([id, mf]) => [id.replace("./", ""), await mf()])));`